# Does the bulk value of items in my backpack count against my limit?

Tags: equipment, encumbrance, pathfinder-2e, weight

My Pathfinder 2e character has a bulk limit of 7. I've purchased an adventurer's pack, which costs 2 bulk but includes a backpack, which can carry up to 4 bulk.

The description of the backpack (Core Rulebook, pg.287) says:

> A backpack holds up to 4 Bulk of items. If you're carrying or stowing the pack rather than wearing it on your back, its bulk is light instead of negligible.

I'm not sure how this interacts with my bulk. I can foresee two options:

1. I can still only carry up to 7 bulk. My backpack can hold 4 bulk byitself, but when I carry or wear the backpack I have to hold its 4 bulk too. It seems like in this case there is no real benefit to a backpack, unless you have to justify *how* you are carrying things.
2. While wearing the backpack, I can carry up to 11 bulk (7 from my limit, 4 from the backpack). This makes the backpack useful, but I don't see this interpretation supported in the rules.

So how does the backpack work? Does the bulk value of the items in my backpack count against my bulk limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Core Rulebook Errata has modified this section of the rules. Under **Changes to Make Bulk Less Restrictive** (Errata Update 1.0 pg 3, Core Rulebook pg 287):

> “The first 2 Bulk of items in your backpack don’t count against your Bulk limits.”

Therefore, the backpack can hold 4 bulk worth of items, and the first 2 bulk don't apply to your encumbered or maximum bulk.

Answer (score -2):

After discussion with WeirdFrog I have to reluctantly agree that Option 1 is correct. Items stored in a backpack are just as bulky for you as items carried any other way.

This raises the question: why use a backpack? But I think any answer to that question is going to fall into the range of opinion and DM/group preferences at the table.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for where in the rules it is implied that the contents of mundane containers don't affect your bulk limit? I'll remove my answer if such a passage exists.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I didn't see any thing in the core rulebook supporting this interpretation. Do you know of something which does?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @WeirdFrog I draw the implication from the text under the headings Bulk, Bulk Values, and Estimating an Item's Bulk. I will edit the answer to point to this. Conceptually, I'm surprised anyone has trouble with this. 2e measures bulk, rather then weight, to simulate awkwardness of handling. Items carried in containers are less awkward to handle -- this is the real-world reason that people store items in containers.

Comment: @jiriku If we're going with a real-world interpretation, an empty hiking pack is much easier to carry than a full one, and an overloaded one can absolutely negatively affect your ability to move freely.

Comment: @WeirdFrog True. OK, I think you've changed my mind on this one. Unfortunately, that leaves me very dissatisfied with the Bulk rules, but the OP asked what the rules WERE, not if I thought the rules were GOOD. C'est la vie.

Comment: I think the better way to look at the usefulness of a backpack (or any worn container) is that it reduces the number of hands required to carry an item by up to two. So, for 4 bulk worth of items, you can carry (but not wield) them with no hands. While the backpack is worn, it also takes no hands to carry, otherwise it requires at least one hand (presumably, this is not explicitly stated but seems obvious) and the weight becomes L (rather than negligible - as mentioned in its description).

Comment: @jiriku I do agree with your sentiment - a backpack also helps balance less wieldy items and it would make some sense to allow it to confer an increased bulk allotment, though this would reduce the value of the Strength stat. It would probably be unbalanced (excuse the pun) to have it allow you to carry 4 additional bulk (nearly doubling base carrying capacity), even if it might be realistic (considering the value of a properly packed backpack to hikers and soldiers alike). But since many tables eschew the bookkeeping of inventory weight altogether, it could make a good house rule.

Answer (score -3):

The adventurer's pack is actually neither empty nor full, but stocked with helpful items* while leaving space for more gear to be stowed.  The total Bulk of the items adds up to 1 Bulk.  This (1 Bulk) has been confirmed by Paizo as the correct bulk for the adventurer's pack.  The 2 Bulk entry was an error.  The backpack, by itself does not raise or lower your Bulk carry limit, But instead seems to serve as flavor.  If you didn't buy any pack, it would be assumed that you stowed your gear somewhere, but having a pack lets you describe exactly where.

*(1 bedroll, two belt pouches, 10 pcs chalk, flint and steel, 2 weeks rations, soap, 5 torches, and a waterskin)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to note that we're not a forum and we don't do discussion; answers should directly answer the question rather than attempting to respond to other answers. In this case, the asker is interested in whether the bulk of items stored in their backpack count against their character's bulk limit, or only the backpack's bulk.